# "ellos" or "los", which one is correct?

Tags: gramática

What is the difference between  "ellos" and "los"?

Can I say this?

> A la mañana siguiente ella despertó a decir que el jefe querían ellos por teléfono.

Or is this the correct one?

> La próxima mañana los despertó para decir que el Jefe los quiso por teléfono.

Answer (score 4):

Both *ellos* and *los* are pronouns, but they are used in different parts of the speech. *Ellos* is used as subject in a sentence, while *los* is the object; much the same difference there is in English between *they* and *them*.

In your example, you want an object, so the right word is *los*. Correcting a few other mistakes, the right sentence might be:

> A la mañana siguente ella los despertó para decirles que el jefe **los** quería por teléfono.

Comment: In other words, to be clear, OP's second sentence has the correct pronoun (peeling away a few little problems).